# WCF Web Deploy HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf, web-deployment

I have created a REST WCF web service in vb.net and published it to 1&1 Host Server using Web Deploy. When trying to call one of the services, I keep receiving:

> HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have looked at the wwwroot directory and I can find the .svc files and web.config, so I can't figure out why it can not find it. The call I am making is: http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetTimesheetDetails/1/1/11256/2017-8-9

```js
<OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="GetTimesheetDetails/{userid}/{organisationid}/{jobid}/{sdate}")>
    Function GetTimesheetDetails(ByVal userid As String, ByVal organisationid As String, ByVal jobid As String, ByVal sdate As String) As List(Of JobEngineerTime)
```

I have tested these calls running them on Visual Studio and it works fine, unfortunately I am unable to get it to run through the 1&1 server.

This is my web.config:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--Disabled custom errors to allow display of detailed errors.-->
    <!--<customErrors mode="Off"/>-->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Errors/500.htm">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/404.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WCFTimesheetWebService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFTimesheetWebService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WCFTimesheetWebService.Service2">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFTimesheetWebService.IService2" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WCFTimesheetWebService.Service3">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFTimesheetWebService.IService3" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Allowing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - The httpProtocol settings allow web services to be called from external domains using JavaScript-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: It might be an issue with the hosting environment.  I suggest you talk to 1&1 or check their support forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of mappings were missing in IIS "Handler Mappings". To sort out the problem, all I had to do was click on "Revert to Parent" inside "Handler Mappings" which restored the missing mappings and it started working.